# Cannot install Django on Work PC

Tags: python, django, pip, pypi

I have installed python on my work pc and I am trying to install django via pip. For the installation i use the following command:

```
pip install django
```

However the outcome is the following:

```
..Collecting Django
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django <from version:>
No matching distribution found for django
```

Is this because I am on my work pc and there is some problem with the proxy or is this some other problem ?

Need some assistance please. Thanks

This is the output for `pip Django --verbose`

```
C:\Users\asangar1>pip install django --verbose
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org
There was an error checking the latest version of pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\outdated.py", line 122, in pip_v
ersion_check
    headers={"Accept": "application/json"},
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 47
7, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 373, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 46
5, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 57
3, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\adapter.py", line
 46, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\adapters.py", line 43
1, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590
)
Collecting django
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/: connection error:
EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590) - skipping
  1 location(s) to search for versions of django:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/
  Starting new HTTPS connection (2): pypi.python.org
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/: connection error:
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590) - skippi
ng
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django (from versions:
 )
Cleaning up...
No matching distribution found for django
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 223, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 280, in run

    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 317, in prepare_
files
    functools.partial(self._prepare_file, finder))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 304, in _walk_re
q_to_install
    more_reqs = handler(req_to_install)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 439, in _prepare
_file
    req_to_install.populate_link(finder, self.upgrade)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 244, in popu
late_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 563, in find_requireme
nt
    'No matching distribution found for %s' % req
DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for django
```

Comment: It's `pip install Django`, with a capital. Unfortunately.

Comment: I still get the same error also with capital

Comment: Why don't you ask your IT department?

Comment: If you have proxy at work then it can definitely be the issue. Take a look at this link for setting the proxy variables: http://www.putorius.net/2012/09/how-to-set-httpproxy-variable-in-linux.html

Comment: i was about to say the same thing, does pip anything work?

Comment: The easiest way to test if it is the proxy is to route your wireless through your phone and see if it starts the download. Obviously I am not suggesting downloading all of Django through your phone unless you have free data and the time.

Comment: can you run `pip install django --verbose` and post the output?

Comment: so pip "anything" does not work. I can't install anything with pip. It works through the wireless system but I needed it on the computer and I can't connect the computer to the wireless network. I have also posted pip install Django --verbose